# With a Flame Runner, do you turn, Drift, and turn the other way immediately to not turn so much?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

With a Flame Runner, Mach Bike, and Bullet Bike, I found that they all turn too much, so they almost always run to the side of the road before the mini-turbo can come out.

Somebody suggested initiating the turn early, is that the way to do it?  Because earlier means turning too much early.

A way I found that might work is to 1) Turn 2) press Drift 3) Turn THE OTHER WAY IMMEDIATELY.  So the turning will be minimized. (bigger turning radius)

Is this how it is done or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that turning against the drift makes it take longer to get the mini-boost, I tend to drive these karts and bikes exactly like the N64 version of Mario Kart, where you had to move the stick from side to side to get the boost.

1. Initiate turn and drift.
2. Steer against the drift.
3. Briefly steer back into the drift to get the boost.
4. Repeat 2 and 3, if necessary, depending on how tightly you need to turn and how quickly you want the boost.

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the best ways to do it.  Basically, some vehicles have sharper drift radii than others, so finding ways to compensate is up to you.  For me, I found that turning the opposite direction immediately is one of the best strategies.  You could also try turning the other way a bit **before** initiating your drift, but then you will take a slightly longer route around the turn, and lose time.  I suggest you keep at it the way you are right now.